# Linux equivalent of OS X "Launchd", with respect to use by non-root users?

Tags: process, desktop, init, supervisord

Is there a good way for non-root users to start "managed" processes?  In this case, I am using 
managed" to describe a process that starts up when the user logs in, is monitored by some sort of process supervisor (like `init`), restarted if it fails, and has its stdout/stderr logged somewhere automatically.

I have over time hacked together a few solutions on my own running something like [runit](http://smarden.org/runit/) or [supervisor](http://supervisord.org/), but neither has been particularly well integrated into my desktop environment or the system in general.  Is there a standard solution for this sort of thing?

Comment: The closest I've seen is runit's user-controlled services, which is a pity that it's not used more often, if only because there isn't a huge API layer or CPU-gobbling overhead involved in the setup.  The `systemd` folks are pushing hard right now, and I suspect it will be a matter of time before someone has the same idea with it.

Comment: Wow, this is an old question :).  systemd now has support for user-controlled services, e.g. as documented [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd/User).

Comment: Indeed.  I only recently started with `runit` for personal use because I wasn't a fan of systemd's "all in one" approach.  As far as machines at work go, I don't care if they run systemd or not, I only care that they stay up and running. :)